# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to write code as below:

```py
for i in range(1,13):
    'test{}'.format(i) = """
select * from test_table where month(date_time) = {}
""".format(i)
```

But I got the following syntax error: `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to assign to variables named `test1`, `test2` etc.?

Comment: Yes, I would like to  assign to variables named test1, test2

Comment: While what you are trying is possible, it's messy, consider just appending each result to a list.

Comment: please read this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask a question.

Comment: @HamzaFarooq What's wrong with my question?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to make variable variable names. That's almost always the wrong choice — you should be using a dictionary or list. [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: You will better know after you read the guide I've attached earlier in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary instead:

```
d = {}
for i in range(1, 13):
    d["test{0}".format(i)] = "select * from test_table where month(date_time) = {0}".format(i)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'test1': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 1', 'test2': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 2', 'test3': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 3', 'test4': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 4', 'test5': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 5', 'test6': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 6', 'test7': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 7', 'test8': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 8', 'test9': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 9', 'test10': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 10', 'test11': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 11', 'test12': 'select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 12'}
```

Now you can access a certain key like:

```
print(d['test3'])
```

to get a certain value:

```
select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 3
```

You could also do something like:

```
for i in range(1, 13):
    globals()['test%s' % i] = "select * from test_table where month(date_time) = {0}".format(i)

print(test3)
```

to get

```
select * from test_table where month(date_time) = 3
```

but using globals is a bad idea, usually dictionaries or lists should be used in these scenarios.

Comment: Thanks so so so much for your detailed answer!!!

Comment: Hi, you said that's a bad practice, which one would be a good practice? I want to solve my problem, and I wanna a good one

Comment: The first solution is more natural and easier to understand so that’s why it’s the better solution. The second one is harder to understand and less natural, so I would prefer to use the first solution.

Comment: Got it, thanks so so so much for your help!!!!! Have a nice day